# chrome 64 video element attribute muted is Unavailable

Tags: google-chrome, html5-video

chrome 64 video element attribute muted is Unavailable, the reason:

```
element.muted = true
```

instead of

```
$("element").attr("muted", true)
```

or

```
<video muted src="">
```